# Setting imagesource of image inside controltemplate for different controls in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I have created a Style for circular button in windows application. I am using this style to make the buttons appear circular. Code for the Style is below:

```
<Style x:Key="CircularButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="#FFF8F1F1"  />
                        <Image Width="50" Height="50" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am using like below :

```
<Button x:Name="btnFacebook" Style="{StaticResource CircularButton}"  Click="btnFacebook_Click" Visibility="Visible" Margin="10,0"  />
```

Now I have many buttons on the page that need to be circular,but need to have different background images.Is there any way to set the image source of this style for different buttons.I have tried code like below:

```
<Button x:Name="btnTwitter" Style="{StaticResource CircularButton}"  Click="btnTwitter_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0">
   <ControlTemplate>
   <Image Source="Images/appbar.social.twitter.png"/>
   </ControlTemplate>
</Button>
```

Also I have tried placing the image directly inside the button content , or using the template binding for showing the image inside the button.Is there any way of doing this without creating different styles for different buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CircularButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="#FFF8F1F1"  />
                    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button x:Name="btnTwitter" Style="{StaticResource CircularButton}"   Click="btnTwitter_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0">
   <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/appbar.social.twitter.png"/>
</Button>
```